# PDO - query giving no results

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

This is my prepared statment.

```
SELECT `id`, `title`, `image`, `discount`, `price`, `new_price`, `img_url` FROM `deals` WHERE `active`="1" AND `category`=:ctid AND `img_url`!=""  AND `Brands`=:p1 ORDER BY `order`, `id` ASC LIMIT 0, 12;
```

This is the array that i am using in `bindParam`.

```
Array
(
    [:ctid] => 1
    [:p1] => Apple
)
```

Here's the PHP code:

```
$sql = 'SELECT `id`, `title`, `image`, `discount`, `price`, `new_price`, `img_url` FROM `deals` WHERE `active`="1" AND `category`=:ctid AND `img_url`!=""  AND `Brands`=:p1 ORDER BY `order`, `id` ASC LIMIT 0, 12;';
$sql = $link->prepare( $sql );

$binders = array(
  ':ctid' => 1,
  ':p1' => 'Apple'
);

foreach( $binders as $key => $value ) {
    $sql->bindParam( $key, $value );
}

$sql->execute();
$sql->setFetchMode( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
$result = $sql->fetchAll();
```

This gives no result.

But, if i do a direct query, i get results from the db. What could be wrong in the above query.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked any errors?

Comment: can you please add results that you get from direct query? So we will be able to see what do you have in the database...

Comment: @u_mulder Not getting any errors.

Comment: @RamSharma Column names are case-insensitive in MySQL.

Comment: I think the problem is with `bindParam` as it's binded by reference. Have you tried `bindValue`?

Comment: Post that as an answer @u_mulder.

Comment: @u_mulder You were right! `bindValue` works, not sure what `bindParam` means by binding by reference. Please post that as an answer.

Comment: @web-nomad bindParam means if you were taking it from a POST value `$_POST['var']` or GET parameter, but since you are passing your values in the array directly, you need to use bindValue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you binding parameters with `bindParam`, which uses binding by reference. In your case you should use `bindValue` instead:

```
foreach( $binders as $key => $value ) {
    $sql->bindValue( $key, $value );
}
```

Or you can pass your array directly to `execute()` method:

```
$sql->execute( $binders );
```

As described in manual:

`the variable is bound as a reference and will only be evaluated at the time that PDOStatement::execute() is called.`

So when your foreach loop ends `$value` has value of last array item `Apple`. So when `execute` runs, both `:ctid` and `:p1` values are becoming equal to `Apple`. Surely, this is not what you want)

Comment: This works, still am not sure about why should `bindParam` not work. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh man...the manual should point this out specifically. Thanks for clarifying it. Wish i can upvote it a 100 times :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this to bindvalue

```
$sql = 'SELECT `id`, `title`, `image`, `discount`, `price`, `new_price`, `img_url` FROM `deals` WHERE `active`="1" AND `category`=:ctid AND `img_url`!=""  AND `Brands`=:p1 ORDER BY `order`, `id` ASC LIMIT 0, 12;';
$link->prepare($sql);
$link->execute([
    ':ctid' => 1,
    ':p1' => 'Apple'
]);
$result = $link->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```